# How to perform a cycle on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this TensorFlow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.device("gpu:0"):
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    w = tf.Variable([1, 1, 1], dtype=tf.float32, name="weights")

    examples = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32, name="examples")
    exampleId = tf.placeholder(shape=(), name="example_id", dtype=tf.int32)

    updatew = tf.assign_sub(w, tf.gather_nd(examples, [exampleId]))

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


    for exId in range(2):
        sess.run(updatew, {exampleId:exId})

    print(w.eval())
```

The actual code is obviously more complex, but this example is enough for the question.

Basically:

- I have a huge computational graph `G`
- A dataset of examples `D` loaded on the GPU
- I need to process each example in the dataset `D` via the graph `G`

If I cycle on the examples outside of the GPU (like in the example above) the code is incredibly slow, slower than the current C++ implementation of the same learning algorithm.

I would like to cycle over the examples in `D` with a `while` loop (or similar) located inside of the graph `G` and thus on the GPU.

I cannot use FIFO queues since they are CPU-only.

Is there anyone who has an idea on how to accomplish that? TensorFlow has plenty of classes to iterate over mini-batches using 'standard' functions, but I could not find a way to iterate over the dataset and modify `w`.

Comment: Did you look at control flow graph ops? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop

Comment: There are problems with the while loop (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978333/understanding-the-while-semantics): nodes place outside of the while get evaluated once.

Comment: That is mighty weird. Let me run a few tests here.

Comment: Since I did not receive any answer to that question, I asked on the TensorFlow forums: it is normal that nodes placed outside of the while get evaluated only once. It looks like queues are the way to go, but they are only implemented on the CPU-side.